# How am I misunderstanding sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score?

Tags: scikit-learn, roc, multi-class

The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html) for scikit-learn sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score() contains two statements regarding the 'average' parameter that, together, are confusing me:

> Note: multiclass ROC AUC currently only handles the ‘macro’ and ‘weighted’ averages.

and

> Will be ignored when y_true is binary

But won't y_true always be binary if the problem is not multiclass? In that case, it only takes this parameter if multiclass, and so the options other than 'macro' and 'average' aren't ever available. Or what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're missing the *multilabel* option.

Going through the [implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L363) you might distinguish the [`'multiclass'`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L548) branch where [`._multiclass_roc_auc_score()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L561) is called and where you might see that the available options are indeed only `('macro', 'weighted')` (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L635) for reference); then, again, you might distinguish the [`'binary'`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L564) and the [`'multilabel-indicator'`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L574) branches where [`._average_binary_score()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7e1e6d09bcc2eaeba98f7e737aac2ac782f0e5f1/sklearn/metrics/_base.py#L23) is called. When considering a *multilabel* target, all weighting options are available.

Indeed, the documentation of `sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score()` states that

> this implementation can be used with binary, multiclass and ***multilabel*** classification.

The [`sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.multiclass.type_of_target.html) function is a utility in `sklearn` that returns an encoding of the target type (given the target `y` itself). It is indeed what the implementation uses in the branches referenced above to determine the label type and therefore to detect whether you're approaching a *binary*, a *multiclass* or a *multilabel* classification problem.

Following the documentation for `type_of_target()` you might see that `'binary'`, `'multiclass'`, `'multilabel-indicator'` are not the only types of target existing in `sklearn`, though being the only ones that can be used within `.roc_auc_score()`.

Comment: Ah, I guess I had a binary mindset then when I was thinking that there was only one alternative :P